# how to display function calculation in html using button with eventhandler

Tags: javascript, html

```js
//area = 1/2 b * h

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', findArea);

function findArea(base, height) {
  var base = document.getElementById("base").value;
  var height = document.getElementById("height").value;

  var area = base * height / 2;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  return result.textContent = area;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="base">
  <p>Enter base measurement</p>
  <input type="number" id="height">
  <p>Enter height measurement</p>
  <button id='btn'>Click to find the area of your triangle.</button>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Can someone tell me why the result of the returned calculation flashes and then disappears from the screen? I would like it to remain there until another set of numbers are input for a new round-thank you…

Comment: Because you're submitting your form?

Comment: Thank you for your help-it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The default action of a button within a form is to submit it. Give your button the attribute type of button to prevent the form submission:

```js
//area = 1/2 b * h

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', findArea);

function findArea(base, height) {
  var base = document.getElementById("base").value;
  var height = document.getElementById("height").value;

  var area = base * height / 2;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  return result.textContent = area;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="base">
  <p>Enter base measurement</p>
  <input type="number" id="height">
  <p>Enter height measurement</p>
  <button type="button" id='btn'>Click to find the area of your triangle.</button>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: upvoted because it hints at the subtle, underlying thing that makes a button click submit or not - a "plain-old button" vice a "submit button" - i.e. `type="button"` vs `type="submit"`. This is fundamental form-ology that must be groked.  Although I must say [the preventDefault() answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53403492/463206) makes the "do not submit this form" intent very explicit. But can we say that what is actually form "default"  is the button's `type="submit"`?

Comment: Thanks Michael, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting form, and form will go to action...so that you need prevent default form action, and you can do this by using `event.preventDefault();` for html form tag.

Just edit your form tag by adding: `onsubmit="event.preventDefault();"` and all will work fine.

```js
//area = 1/2 b * h

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', findArea);

function findArea(base, height) {
  var base = document.getElementById("base").value;
  var height = document.getElementById("height").value;

  var area = base * height / 2;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  return result.textContent = area;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
  <input type="number" id="base">
  <p>Enter base measurement</p>
  <input type="number" id="height">
  <p>Enter height measurement</p>
  <button id='btn'>Click to find the area of your triangle.</button>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Anees Hikmat Abu Hmiad, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome mate, Good luck :D